# Remove Bracket [*TESTABC*] along with content from String prefix in java

Tags: regex, string, replace, prefix, java-6

I am having string as below and want prefix to be removed `[*TESTABC*]`

```
String a = "[*TESTABC*]test@test.com";
```

Expected result: `test@test.com`

I tried below code but it is removing the bracklets only. I need to remove the inner content also.

The string with come in this pattern only. Please help.

```
String s = "[*TESTABC*]test@test.com";
 String regex = "\\[|\\]";
 s = s.replaceAll(regex, "");
 System.out.println(s); //*TESTABC*test@test.com
```

Comment: So, remove `"\\[[^\\]\\[]*]"` pattern matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index;
String s = "[*TESTABC*]test@test.com";
index=s.indexOf(']');
s=s.substring(index+1);
System.out.println(s);
```

**i solve your question according to your problem and output **